# Chrome extension using React Native, a good or bad idea?

Tags: react-native, google-chrome-extension

We are building an app that will be available on iOS, Android, and as a Chrome extension.
We are considering to use React Native for these three platforms.
I cannot find many accounts of React Native being used for building Chrome extensions, but there is one guide that explains how to do this: https://mmazzarolo.com/blog/2021-09-25-running-react-native-everywhere-electron-browser-ext/.

So, since there is not much information available, we are not sure what is best: Building the Chrome extension cross-platform or building it separately.
Would cross-platform be an efficient solution for a chrome extension or would we encounter problems?

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: Did you do it ?

Comment: Nope, didn't do it in the end. We are just using React.js for the Chrome extension.